# Wordpress pagination with this loop

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Can you help me to find the right code for pagination with this loop?
Here is my loop:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=1&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=2&offset=1&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=6&offset=3&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
...
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

This was my old loop, how can I convert it to the new one? Unfortunately I don't know how php works..

```
<?php 
   if (is_front_page() ) {
           get_header( 'front' );

    } else {
           get_header();
   }
?>

<section id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
<?php query_posts('showposts=1&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-principale expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php    the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="destacado"><h3>Destacado</h3></div>
                <header class="testo-articolo">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php comments_template(); ?><!-- da sistemare -->
                </header>
        </article>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=2&offset=1&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
        <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-destra expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <header class="testo-articolo-destra expand-image">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </header>
            <div class="badge1"></div>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
<?php query_posts('showposts=6&offset=3&post_type=post'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <article class="thumbnail distanza expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive ingrandire-img')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <header class="testo-articolo">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('Ningún comentario', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lee más', 'katartika' ); ?></a></p>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display</p>

<?php endif; ?>


</div><!-- /row -->
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <?php posts_nav_link(‘|’, ‘Prossimo’, ‘Precedente’); ?>
</div>
</section>
</div><!-- /sezione -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You can do all of that in one query without a custom query which you can paginate as normal. One **BIG** note, you should never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks pagination and the main query

Comment: I need a custom query because I want to show posts in different ways, so this is the only method I found to customize (add class and so on) each part of it. Do you know any other method to get it? What can I use instead of query_posts ?

Comment: You can still do it in one query, just use a counter or the build in loop counter. Use the default loop. I'm off to bed now unfortunately, will probably have a look at this tommorow. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have stated last night, you can do this in one query, and without a custom query.

I would like to enforce the fact that you should **never** use `query_posts`. `query_posts` breaks paginations, rerun queries slowing your page performance and breaks the main query object which is needed by many plugins or custom functions. It is truely an evil way to run custom queries which should be avoided at all costs. If you ever need to run custom queries, use `WP_Query` for paginated queries and `get_posts` for non paginated queries.

You should also never replace the main query with a custom one on the home page and any archive type page, this breaks page functionalities. Custom queries should only be run for secondary posts like sliders, featured content, related and popular posts and on page templates and static front pages to display custom posts. If you ever need to alter the main query on the homepage or and archive page, use `pre_get_posts`

Now, to solve your issue, you need one loop from the main query and a counter, in this case we will use the build in main query counter `$wp_query->current_post` (one note, this counter starts at `0`, so post one in the loop will be `0`, post two will be `1`, etc).

From what I read from your code, the first code needs to be different from post two and three, and these are different from the next six

Lets put that into code

```
if ( have_posts() ) {

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

            /*
             * Display different outlay for post one
             */
        if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) {

            // Do what needs to be done for post one

        } elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current post <= 2 ) {

            /* 
             * Do something for posts 2 and 3
             */

        } elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) {

            /*
             * Do something for the rest of the posts
             */

        }
    }

}
```

### EDIT

You can convert your code to

```
<?php 
   if (is_front_page() ) {
           get_header( 'front' );

    } else {
           get_header();
   }
?>

<section id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
 if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { ?>
        <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-principale expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php    the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="destacado"><h3>Destacado</h3></div>
                <header class="testo-articolo">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="entry-meta">
                        <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                    </div>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <?php comments_template(); ?><!-- da sistemare -->
                </header>
        </article>
    </div>

<?php

} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current post <= 2 ) { ?>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
        <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-destra expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <header class="testo-articolo-destra expand-image">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </header>
            <div class="badge1"></div>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php 

} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) { ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <article class="thumbnail distanza expand-image">
            <div class="featured-image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive ingrandire-img')); ?></a>
            </div>
            <header class="testo-articolo">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('Ningún comentario', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lee más', 'katartika' ); ?></a></p>
            </header>
        </article>
    </div>

<?php }

endwhile; 
endif; ?>


</div><!-- /row -->
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <?php posts_nav_link(‘|’, ‘Prossimo’, ‘Precedente’); ?>
</div>
</section>
</div><!-- /sezione -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very helpful, I didn't know it.
Will pagination work with this loop? I need this loop only for first page, from the second page I want to show them like the 6 last posts in the first page.

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark next to it and ask a new question with this requirements ;-)

Comment: Sorry, only see your second comment now. It is quite tough adding php tags as how you switch between html and php is not known to me. ;-)

Comment: Also, yes, with the above code you can use normal pagination. If you only need 6 posts from page two onwards, then you will need to use `pre_get_posts` with offsets and recalculating pagination. Also, if you need to target page 1 only, use `if ( !is_paged() )`

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question to change my old loop with the new one

Comment: I'm trying to use your code, but I don't understand how I have to use it

Comment: Please see my edit. It is expected that you at least know how the basics and ho to implement and use code. I have not tested the code, but it should work fine. Just a note, do not post updates or new questions as answers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it this afternoon.
Can you suggest me some tutorial or example about the pagination like I want it to be?

Comment: Unfortantely you need to handle them as indicated by the errors given. I cannot test your code as I have stated. I had one syntax error which I have fixed now.

Comment: I think they are php syntax errors, because dreamweaver advise me in those lines where elseif are.

Comment: Browser doesn't show any error, just an empty page whit this code

Comment: On which page is that, be exact

Comment: I fixed it, now it works.
Can you help me with pagination as you explained?

Comment: I have seen your question. Will look at it on Monday as I cannot code till then due to family responsibilities. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the right way, but I got it:

```
<?php 
if (is_front_page() ) {
       get_header( 'front' );

} else {
       get_header();
}
?>

<section id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">


<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if (!is_paged() && $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { ?>
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
    <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-principale expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php    the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="destacado"><h3>Destacado</h3></div>
            <header class="testo-articolo">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php comments_template(); ?><!-- da sistemare -->
            </header>
    </article>
</div>

<?php

} elseif (!is_paged() &&  $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current_post <= 2 ) { ?>

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
    <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-destra expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <header class="testo-articolo-destra expand-image">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </header>
        <div class="badge1"></div>
    </article>
</div>
<?php 

} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) { ?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <article class="thumbnail distanza expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive ingrandire-img')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <header class="testo-articolo">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('Ningún comentario', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lee más', 'katartika' ); ?></a></p>
        </header>
    </article>
</div>

<?php 
//new request for all the rest of post from page 2 onwards
} elseif ( is_paged() ) { ?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <article class="thumbnail distanza expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive ingrandire-img')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <header class="testo-articolo">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('Ningún comentario', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lee más', 'katartika' ); ?></a></p>
        </header>
    </article>
</div>

<?php }

endwhile; 
endif; ?>


</div><!-- /row -->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php posts_nav_link('|', 'Prossimo', 'Precedente'); ?>
</div>
</section>
</div><!-- /sezione -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```